# Need help understanding the Firebase Storage CDN

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, cdn

I'm building an audiobook app and have uploaded the audio files on Firebase Storage. My problem is that I experience different performances in San Francisco vs Toronto. I am under the impression that Firebase Storage has built-in CDN. if so, Do I need to enable it somewhere? if not, how do I add GCP CDN to my Firebase Storage files behind Firebase Auth??

Checking the domain `storage.googleapis.com` which is where my Firebase Storage files are hosted shows that it is using the Google CDN.

Here are the response headers for one of my public audio file request:

```
accept-ranges: bytes
alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,44,43,39"
cache-control: public, max-age=3600
content-disposition: inline; filename*=utf-8''G4PT7dPIyEuIz74BtTmm_FallIsTheLastSeasonOfTheYear.mp3
content-length: 3162637
content-type: audio/mp3
date: Tue, 30 Apr 2019 17:13:34 GMT
etag: "98013599e6f108a0edeeaac7c8b2bb45"
expires: Tue, 30 Apr 2019 18:13:34 GMT
last-modified: Mon, 08 Apr 2019 17:59:58 GMT
server: UploadServer
status: 200
x-goog-generation: 1554746398034230
x-goog-hash: crc32c=TKSAfA==, md5=mAE1mebxCKDt7qrHyLK7RQ==
x-goog-meta-firebasestoragedownloadtokens: da578546-c265-4f06-ae11-6273a7812bf2
x-goog-metageneration: 2
x-goog-storage-class: STANDARD
x-goog-stored-content-encoding: identity
x-goog-stored-content-length: 3162637
x-guploader-uploadid: AEnB2UqdvgzkJMC0yHJkGbr-K5cWWbXK5I2j6NLtd4NwG1G9swIhhp1QC8G25JUK4LItZID0IxuYhhLta3YImMTtzbKkr5vcEQ
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I reached out to Firebase Support and here is the answer I got:

> Regarding the CDN question, the short answer is no, Cloud Storage has no built-in CDN; the less short answer is: when your Cloud Storage
>   is "multi-regional", it means that "hot content" (frequently accessed
>   content) is available on different locations, but that is limited to
>   multi-regional locations, and it applies only to the "jurisdiction" of
>   the location, so, for example, if your project is in "us-central",
>   then your multi-regional Storage will be stored only in the US data
>   centers, so when accessed from Toronto, it will be served from the
>   nearest US datacenter.
>
> Now, there are ways to add a CDN to Cloud Storage content; I found
>   this small guide using Google CDN:
>   https://medium.com/@marco_37432/create-a-custom-domain-cdn-with-google-beta-7ad9531dfbae
>
> Another use that I have seen is creating a static website with Cloud
>   Storage and adding on top another CDN provider, like CloudFlare. You
>   can see more details in this links:
>
> https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/09/push-google-cloud-origin-content-out-to-users.html
>   https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/docs/how-to/cdn-interconnect